# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 16 path $.locations[0]

Tags: java, android, android-volley

## code for response class

```
public class LocationHealth implements HealthStatusIdentifiable{

@SerializedName("health")
int health;
@SerializedName("location")
String location;
@SerializedName("company")
String company;
@SerializedName("pos")
CompanyPos companyPos;
@SerializedName("rosters")
RosterHealth rosterHelath;
@SerializedName("cafe_tabs")
CafeHealth cafeHealth;


public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public CompanyPos getCompanyPos() {
    return companyPos;
}

public void setCompanyPos(CompanyPos companyPos) {
    this.companyPos = companyPos;
}

public RosterHealth getRosterHelath() {
    return rosterHelath;
}

public void setRosterHelath(RosterHealth rosterHelath) {
    this.rosterHelath = rosterHelath;
}

public CafeHealth getCafeHealth() {
    return cafeHealth;
}

public void setCafeHealth(CafeHealth cafeHealth) {
    this.cafeHealth = cafeHealth;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return location+" : "+company+" : "+health;
}

@Override
public int getHealthStatus() {
    if(health==100){
        return GOOD;
    }else if(health>50){
        return WARN;
    }else
        return ALERT;
}
```

}

/*CompanyPos.java*/

```
 public class CompanyPos implements HealthStatusIdentifiable{

@SerializedName("inactive")
int inactive;
@SerializedName("active")
int active;
@SerializedName("name")
String name;
@SerializedName("health")
int health;


public int getTotal(){
    return inactive+active;
}

public int getInactive() {
    return inactive;
}

public void setInactive(int inactive) {
    this.inactive = inactive;
}

public int getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(int active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

@Override
public int getHealthStatus() {
    if(inactive==0)
        return GOOD;
    if(inactive==1)
        return WARN;
    else
        return ALERT;
} }
```

JSON FORMAT

> {   "locations": [
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 7,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "FS-Cafeteria-Bangalore",
>         "company": "FirstSource",
>         "location_id": 1,
>         "company_id": 1
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Cafe-Hyderabad",
>         "company": "General Electric",
>         "location_id": 19,
>         "company_id": 5
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Shankar Narayan Building",
>         "company": "Infinera",
>         "location_id": 84,
>         "company_id": 22
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "RMZ Eco Space",
>         "company": "Northern Trust",
>         "location_id": 82,
>         "company_id": 70
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 2,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "SMS",
>         "company": "Genpact",
>         "location_id": 79,
>         "company_id": 67
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Surya Tech Park",
>         "company": "Genpact",
>         "location_id": 78,
>         "company_id": 67
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 2,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Pritech",
>         "company": "Genpact",
>         "location_id": 77,
>         "company_id": 67
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "BNGLO.G-ETAMIN -CSR",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 70,
>         "company_id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 2,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Aneja Towers",
>         "company": "FirstSource",
>         "location_id": 69,
>         "company_id": 1
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 3,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "TECCI Park",
>         "company": "FirstSource",
>         "location_id": 68,
>         "company_id": 1
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 2,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "ETA PARK-Chennai",
>         "company": "FirstSource",
>         "location_id": 67,
>         "company_id": 1
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Prestige Solitaire Building",
>         "company": "Infinera",
>         "location_id": 44,
>         "company_id": 22
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "RMZ Eco World",
>         "company": "Epicor",
>         "location_id": 2,
>         "company_id": 3
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 2,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "TVH Agnitio Park",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 20,
>         "company_id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 2,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "ABB-BTP",
>         "company": "ABB",
>         "location_id": 8,
>         "company_id": 7
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 2,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "GE-Bengaluru",
>         "company": "General Electric",
>         "location_id": 5,
>         "company_id": 5
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 3,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "BNGLO.E",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 15,
>         "company_id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "BNGLO.D",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 14,
>         "company_id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 3,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "BNGLO.C",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 13,
>         "company_id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 3,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "INDIA. N & T",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 12,
>         "company_id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "BNGLO.B",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 11,
>         "company_id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "BNGLO. H- Vector",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 10,
>         "company_id": 2
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 1,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Britannia Cafe",
>         "company": "Britannia",
>         "location_id": 17,
>         "company_id": 8
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 4,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "BT- Ecoworld",
>         "company": "British Telecom",
>         "location_id": 7,
>         "company_id": 6
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "inactive": 2,
>           "active": 0
>         },
>         "health": 66,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "BT- Pritech",
>         "company": "British Telecom",
>         "location_id": 6,
>         "company_id": 6
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "active": 0,
>           "inactive": 0
>         },
>         "health": 100,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "ABB-HEBBAL",
>         "company": "ABB",
>         "location_id": 85,
>         "company_id": 7
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "active": 0,
>           "inactive": 0
>         },
>         "health": 100,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Corporate",
>         "company": "Corporate",
>         "location_id": 4,
>         "company_id": 4
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "active": 0,
>           "inactive": 0
>         },
>         "health": 100,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Paladion Cafe",
>         "company": "Paladion",
>         "location_id": 18,
>         "company_id": 9
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "active": 0,
>           "inactive": 0
>         },
>         "health": 100,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Mystifly",
>         "company": "Mystifly",
>         "location_id": 81,
>         "company_id": 68
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "active": 0,
>           "inactive": 0
>         },
>         "health": 100,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Whitefield",
>         "company": "Technicolor",
>         "location_id": 80,
>         "company_id": 69
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "active": 0,
>           "inactive": 0
>         },
>         "health": 100,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "TEK MEDOWS-Chennai",
>         "company": "FirstSource",
>         "location_id": 66,
>         "company_id": 1
>       },
>       {
>         "pos": {
>           "active": 0,
>           "inactive": 0
>         },
>         "health": 100,
>         "rosters": {
>           "attended": 0,
>           "rosters": 0
>         },
>         "cafe_tabs": {
>           "live_tabs": 0,
>           "total_cafe_tabs": 0
>         },
>         "location": "Bagmane Tech Park",
>         "company": "Qualcomm",
>         "location_id": 86,
>         "company_id": 2
>       }   ] }
>
> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 16 path $.locations[0]

Comment: generate json to pojo again, there is some problem in this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping is incorrect. Your response indicates that you getting one object back that has an array.

Add this class

```
public class MyResponse{
@SerialisedName("locations")
    List< LocationHealthResponse > locationHealthList;
}
```

and your call would be `Call<MyResponse> getResponse()` instead of `Call<LocationHealth> getResponse()`

Comment: in which class i have to add this

Comment: Make a new class

Comment: how i am going call this class

Comment: How are you currently calling it?

Comment: **this is the response class**                                                               
                                                                                                            
 public class LocationHealthResponse {

    @SerializedName("locations")
    HashMap<Long, LocationHealth> locationHealthMap;

    public HashMap<Long, LocationHealth> getLocationHealthMap() {
        return locationHealthMap;
    }

    public void setLocationHealthMap(HashMap<Long, LocationHealth> locationHealthMap) {
        this.locationHealthMap = locationHealthMap;
    }
}

Comment: SimpleHttpAgent<LocationHealthResponse> locationHealthAgent = new SimpleHttpAgent<LocationHealthResponse>(

Comment: SimpleHttpAgent<List<MyResponse>> locationHealthAgent = new SimpleHttpAgent<List<MyResponse>>

Answer (score 0):

Use [pojo generator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to make pojo class

Answer (score 0):

Using the given JSON data, this is the proper structure of POJO Classes.

Don't forget to add package name in all classes.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Overall {

    private List<Location> locations = null;

    public List<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Location {

    private Pos pos;
    private Integer health;
    private Rosters rosters;
    private CafeTabs cafeTabs;
    private String location;
    private String company;
    private Integer locationId;
    private Integer companyId;

    public Pos getPos() {
        return pos;
    }

    public void setPos(Pos pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public Integer getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(Integer health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public Rosters getRosters() {
        return rosters;
    }

    public void setRosters(Rosters rosters) {
        this.rosters = rosters;
    }

    public CafeTabs getCafeTabs() {
        return cafeTabs;
    }

    public void setCafeTabs(CafeTabs cafeTabs) {
        this.cafeTabs = cafeTabs;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }    

    public Integer getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public Integer getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Integer companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Pos {

    private Integer inactive;
    private Integer active;

    public Integer getInactive() {
        return inactive;
    }    

    public void setInactive(Integer inactive) {
        this.inactive = inactive;
    }

    public Integer getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Integer active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Rosters {

    private Integer attended;
    private Integer rosters;

    public Integer getAttended() {
        return attended;
    }

    public void setAttended(Integer attended) {
        this.attended = attended;
    }

    public Integer getRosters() {
        return rosters;
    }

    public void setRosters(Integer rosters) {
        this.rosters = rosters;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class CafeTabs {

    private Integer liveTabs;
    private Integer totalCafeTabs;

    public Integer getLiveTabs() {
        return liveTabs;
    }

    public void setLiveTabs(Integer liveTabs) {
        this.liveTabs = liveTabs;
    }

    public Integer getTotalCafeTabs() {
        return totalCafeTabs;
    }

    public void setTotalCafeTabs(Integer totalCafeTabs) {
        this.totalCafeTabs = totalCafeTabs;
    }

}
```